# undefined reference to '__objc_class_name_Fraction'

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I have these files:

**Project.m**

```
#import "Fraction.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Fraction *fraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    [fraction setNumerator: 2];
    [fraction setDenominator: 3];
    [fraction print];
    NSLog(@"%g", [fraction value]);
    [fraction release];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

**Fraction.m**

```
#import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n {
    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) d {
    denominator = d;
}

-(void) print {
    NSLog(@"%i/%i\n", numerator, denominator);
}

-(double) value {
    return (double) numerator / denominator;
}
@end
```

**Fraction.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction: NSObject {
    int numerator, denominator;
}

-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
-(void) print;
-(double) value;
@end
```

Arranged in a file like so:

```
Objective-C
|_Fraction.h
|_Fraction.m
|_Project.m
```

However, when I run this (I am using `GNUstep`) I get this error:

```
undefined reference to '__objc_class_name_Fraction'
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is telling you that `Fraction.m` was not compiled or linked, and therefore when you build the project, the `Fraction` class was not found.

You'll get this error if you neglect to add `Fraction.m` to your `GNUmakefile`.

You probably have a `GNUmakefile` that looks like:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

TOOL_NAME = MyProject
MyProject_OBJC_FILES = Project.m

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

You want to change that to include `Fraction.m` in the `OBJC_FILES` line:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

TOOL_NAME = MyProject
MyProject_OBJC_FILES = Project.m Fraction.m

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

Clearly, your `makefile` could be different, but you get the idea. Make sure to include `Fraction.m` in your list of source files.

Comment: Ok, now this is going to sound very dumb - but what is a `GNUmakefile` and how do I create one? Thanks.

Comment: You might find these links helpful: http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/ ; http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Make/Manual/make_toc.html ; http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/ProgrammingManual/manual_14.html .

Comment: @Lewis Hmm. I'm not sure how you compiled this without a make file, but I'd refer you to [Building Your First Objective-C Program](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/ProgrammingManual/manual_1.html#Building-Your-First-Objective_002dC-Program). Bottom line, when building an app using the `make` command, a `makefile` (or in this case, `GNUmakefile`) is just a text file that outlines the files/dependencies in building the executable. You just create this makefile in your text editor of choice.